# Is it possible to modify Pydantic BaseModel attributes just after creating it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am starting to learn FastAPI and Pydantic and have a doubt. I have the following subclass of BaseModel

```py
class Product(BaseModel):
  image: str
  name: str
```

After saving this model, I want `image` to store the value `/static/` + `image` so as to create nice hyperlinked REST endpoint. This is possible using `__post_init_post_parse__` hook of pydantic dataclass but since FastAPI currently doesn't support it, I was wondering what can be a workaround this.

Comment: Support for pydantic dataclasses was added in 0.37.0 - what problem are you encountering? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/release-notes/#0370

Answer (score 5):

You could use a custom `validator`:

```
>>> from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
>>> class Product(BaseModel):
    image: str
    name: str
    @validator('image')
    def static_mage(cls, image):
        return '/static/{}'.format(image)


>>> p = Product(image='pic.png', name='product_1')
>>> p
Product(image='/static/pic.png', name='product_1')
```

Comment: This is somehow returning `/static/static/456.png` instead of `/static/456.png` as response in API docs and don't understand why

Comment: It would be nice to see a minimal reproducible example. I will assume that you take an image from one object and insert it into another, i.e. validate it twice